# How to install ubuntu c++ runtimes libraries

Tags: c++

I need c++ runtimes libraries for ubuntu 12.04 but I don't know the package name.
Can someone help me

Manu thanks

Comment: Where did you get these package names from?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

in a terminal.